# pandas to sql - preserve the order of rows from pandas memory to postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

After a lot of processing, I have a pandas dataframe in memory. After the process, I sort the dataframe based on 1 column.

However, when I write this dataframe into the Postgres table, sometimes the order of rows is not preserved, like it was there in the pandas memory.

How can I fix that?

Code snippet:

```
result_df = result_df.sort_values(by=['D1RowNr'])

result_df.to_sql(table_name,engine, schema = schema, 
                 if_exists='replace', index= False, 
                 method = 'multi', chunksize = 300)
```

Size of Data: `~3000 Rows X ~90 Columns`, hence I am using `method= 'multi'` and `chucksize = 300`. Without these parameters, it takes a lot of time, and sometimes the machine hangs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an extra column in the dataframe with the desired order to then `SORT BY` in your `SQL`:

```
result_df['Order'] = result_df.reset_index().index
```

Creating an extra column going from 0 to len(result_df) which you can easily use to SORT BY in your SQL database.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way around that? If I dont want to Order by on the SQL DB?

Comment: I don't think so, I just found this question with the same trouble: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703823/ordering-of-rows-in-pandas-to-sql and the user provides a similar answer.

Comment: Got it, but do you have some infomration on why it happens?

Comment: It seems that the intended behavior, just like dictionaries is for the tables to be unordered, allowing for ordering via SORT BY / ORDER BY

Comment: A relational table is by definition an ***unordered*** set or tuples (rows). There is no such thing order when stored. The only way to get a specific ordering is by using the "ORDER BY" clause on the select statement.